# can not get iOS acceleration value without using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am trying to get IOS `acceleration` value without using storyboard, my purpose is to use the value for calculation purpose.  I do not want to display the value.  I used following methods and each one gives me error:

1) `var acceleration: CMAcceleration`

2) `typedef double UIAccelerationValue;`

```
UIAccelerationValue gravX;
UIAccelerationValue gravY;
UIAccelerationValue gravZ;
```

No error so far, but I am not sure how to get acceleration from here.

3) viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CMMotionManager *motionManager; (this gives error if there is no storyboard)
```

**or**

```
let manager = CMMotionManager; (this gives error, error if let is replaced by var)


AccelViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;
if (manager.accelerometerAvailable) {
manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01f;
[manager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue     mainQueue]
                          withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data,     NSError *error) {
    double accelval = data.acceleration.x;

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `CoreMotion.framework` in your project.

```
Project Target Setting -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> Add Core Motion framework.
```

And Import framework in your viewController file

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```

Hope this will remove your error.